# Missing requirement error on warn command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted the bot to remove the warn role in 1 day however it is giving me an error.
Here is the code I tried I am ok to change the whole code aslong the code work:

```
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def warn(ctx,member:discord.Member, *,reason=None,time:int):
    warn_role=ctx.guild.get_role(811176827803795486)
    time_convert = {"d": 86400}
    tempmute = int(time[0]) * time_convert[time[-1]]

    await member.add_roles(warn_role)
    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has been warned for {reason}')
    await asyncio.sleep(tempmute)
    await member.remove_roles(warn_role)
    await member.send(f'{member.mention} is free to go')
```

error message:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: warn() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'time'
```

Comment: According to the discord.py documentation you can only have a single keyword-only argument. Is that your issue?

Comment: yes, how can I solve it?

Comment: Either `reason` or `time` will have to stop being a keyword-only argument, e.g. `async def warn(ctx, member:discord.Member, time:int, *,reason=None)`

Answer (score 0):

As @Kemp pointed out, you will have to re-order your arguments, so that you can pass in all of them sufficiently.

```py
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def warn(ctx, member : discord.Member, time : int, *, reason=None):
    warn_role=ctx.guild.get_role(811176827803795486)
    time_convert = {"d": 86400}
    tempmute = int(time[0]) * time_convert[time[-1]]

    await member.add_roles(warn_role)
    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has been warned for {reason}')
    await asyncio.sleep(tempmute)
    await member.remove_roles(warn_role)
    await member.send(f'{member.mention} is free to go')
```

So, now you would run it as `warn <member> <time> <reason>`, where `reason` can be more than a single keyword.

Comment: hi thank you for the suggestion but it gives me this error discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: If `time` is an int then what are you expecting `time[-1]` to do?